# How to deal with relative paths in Gradle composite builds?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle composite build with the following directory structure:

```
compositebuildroot/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  componentbuild/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    testfile.txt
```

with `compositebuildroot/build.gradle` containing

```
task runComponentBuildSampleTask {
  dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('componentbuild').task(':sampleTask')
}
```

, `compositebuildroot/settings.gradle` containing

```
rootProject.name = 'compositebuildroot'
includeBuild 'componentbuild'
```

, `compositebuildroot/componentbuild/build.gradle` containing

```
task sampleTask {
  doLast {
    println "System.getProperty(\"user.dir\"): " + System.getProperty("user.dir")
    println new File("testfile.txt").text
  }
}
```

, and `compositebuildroot/componentbuild/settings.gradle` containing

```
rootProject.name = 'componentbuild'
```

.

When I execute `gradle sampleTask` from the `componentbuild` directory, I get the absolute path of the `componentbuild` directory printed out, followed by the contents of `testfile.txt` (which is what I want/expect).  However, when I execute `gradle runComponentBuildSampleTask` from the `compositebuildroot` directory, I get the absolute path of the `compositebuildroot` directory followed by a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for the `testfile.txt` file.

How can I make `gradle runComponentBuildSampleTask` from `compositebuildroot` produce whatever output `gradle sampleTask` from `componentbuild` does?  Is there some way to tell gradle to run component build tasks as if the current directory is that of the component build's settings.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

Never use `new File(...)`

Always use `file(...)`

See [Project.file(Object)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: This seems like a good idea that partially answers the question, so thank you.  Unfortunately, my actual componentbuild is using a plugin that apparently uses `new File(...)` internally, accepting as a parameter a relative path, so things may be a bit more complicated.  And in some other cases, I suspect, we may also not be able to conveniently alter the component build, let alone a plugin.   Any additional ideas?

Comment: Ditch the plugin! Don't trust a plugin that uses `new File(...)` it's written by ametures!

Comment: I will definitely consider that!